# How to identify asp.net or any website is vulnerable to hijacking attacks?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, xss, csrf

We know now a days web masters are worries about the various attacks on their websites.

I want to just know about that how we can check our website irrespective of technologies used to build the website, How we can check our websites to identify or check the following vulnerability.

1. XSS
2. CSRF
3. Clickjacking

or other vulnerability.

Please help anybody on above.

Comment: 1) Religiously follow a prescribed software methodology such as the [Microsoft SDL](https://www.microsoft.com/security/sdl/default.aspx?mstLocPickShow=True). 2) Pay penetration testers to attack it for you. 3) Use static code-analysis tools (e.g. HP Fortify, Veracode, etc.). 4) Code-review your code. 5) Train your developers in security matters. 6) Practice defense-in-depth and attack-surface-reduction techniques. **tl;dr;** There are no quick answers.